# How to execute ssh command via robotframework

Tags: ssh, robotframework

Can someone tell me what mistake i am doing in the following code , I am trying to run a shell command using robot framework and I have installed sshlibrary module using following command - `pip install robotframework-sshlibrary` . But still I am getting error that import SSHLibrary failed.My operating system is Ubuntu14.04.

## Deploy.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library         SSHLibrary
Resource        configuration.txt

*** Variables ***
${OBR_HOST}      10.110.72.192
${OBR_USERNAME}  root
${OBR_PASSWORD}  password

*** Test Cases ***

Deploy OBR machine code 
    ${output}=  Execute Command  /root/deploy.sh
    log to console  ${\n}${output}

*** Keywords ***
open_connection_and_login
    Open Connection  ${OBR_HOST}
    Login  ${OBR_USERNAME}  ${OBR_PASSWORD}
```

## Execution Logs

```
root@92:~# pybot ssh-example.robot 
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/root/ssh-example.robot': Importing test library 'SSHLibrary' failed: ImportError: Importing Paramiko library failed. Make sure you have Paramiko installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SSHLibrary/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .library import SSHLibrary
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SSHLibrary/library.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .client import SSHClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SSHLibrary/client.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pythonclient import PythonSSHClient as SSHClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SSHLibrary/pythonclient.py", line 21, in <module>
    'Importing Paramiko library failed. '
PYTHONPATH:
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/lib/python2.7
  /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
==============================================================================
Ssh-Example                                                                   
==============================================================================
Execute Deploy command                                                | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
No keyword with name 'Open Connection' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ssh-Example                                                           | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
No keyword with name 'Open Connection' found.

Also suite teardown failed:
No keyword with name 'Close All Connections' found.

1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /root/output.xml
Log:     /root/log.html
Report:  /root/report.html
root@92:~# pip install robotframework-sshlibrary
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): robotframework-sshlibrary in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): robotframework in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from robotframework-sshlibrary)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko>=1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from robotframework-sshlibrary)
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Can you please check that paramiko library was installed? `pip list | grep paramiko`. It should be installed by pip automatically as a dependency of sshlibrary.

Comment: `root@92:~# pip list | grep paramiko
paramiko (2.1.2)`   
`root@92:~# python -V
Python 2.7.6`      paramiko library is installed . Will there be any dependency on python version ?

Comment: Rare Case! but worth checking if the system has more than one python versions! and the one to which pybot is related must be updated with SSH lib.

Comment: @MarkHu thanks for update . I have checked the versions and found that different versions were installed .I have installed them with proper versions using `python -m pip install packagename` and it got resolved. 
 `root@92:~# head -n1 $(which pip)
#!/usr/bin/python
root@92:~# head -n1 $(which pybot)
#!/usr/bin/python `

Comment: @Waman and I are on the same wavelength. I've converted my Comment to an Answer, and will accept upvotes as thanks. :)

Comment: Quick Reference http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your error happens in `SSHLibrary/pythonclient.py` before Robot Framework is involved. Try making a little Python script that imports Paramiko. Sometimes `pip` and `pybot` use different versions of Python. Try comparing output of `head -n1 $(which pip)` to `head -n1 $(which pybot)` to check that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar case:

```
Importing test library 'SSHLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named 'SSHLibrary'
```

Thanks to @MarkHu I checked:

```
$ head -n1 $(which pip)
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and:

```
$ head -n1 $(which pybot)
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

One easy solution (from: https://pypi.org/project/robotframework/) is to use python to run "downgrade" the robot version also to 2.7 like this:

```
python -m robot test.robot
```